# Php code not working as well as it should

Tags: php, api, youtube, str-replace

What is the problem with this code?

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/US/most_viewed?v=2&time=all_time';
$site_url = 'http://localhost/';    
// read feed into SimpleXML object
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
// iterate over entries in feed
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
// get nodes in media: namespace for media information
$media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
// get video player URL
$attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
$watch = $attrs['url'];  
$video_id = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '',$watch);
$video_id = str_replace('&feature=youtube_gdata', '',$video_id);
$video_id = str_replace('_player', '',$video_id);
echo $details .= '
'.$site_url.'video/'.$video_id.'';}
```

The code should return a list of 25 url's (via the youtube api feed) with the format:

http://localhost/video/video-id/

But the code returns an ugly list of url's (whith the format i want) mixed and repeated.

PS: before str_replace the links were displayed correctly but with the format:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video-id&feature=youtube_gdata_player

What's wrong? How can i resolve this?

Comment: Can you maybe post the list of the received urls and the list of "ugly" urls you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo `$details .= '..';` $details is not defined before so use `echo $details = '...'`

Comment: thank you. i've didn't saw that. it seems that this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the last line is the problem: you add every entry to $details and echo it additionally. Just put

```
echo $details;
```

behind your loop and remove the echo in the loop, that's all. With your current code, you repeat the content by adding it to the variable AND echoing it.